# No refresh register form

Tags: php, ajax, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created a registration form and it works my only issues is I want to be able to hide the post info in the url if you click submit and the validation fails it does this

register.php?action=signup

is there a mod rewrite for this?
so that the url remains

register.php

removing the ?action=signup

I have searched every where but have came up with nothing

php code for register page

```
                        <?php
                    //Error reporting @1-8F636958
                    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
                    //End Error reporting

                    //Include Common Files @1-EDC1CE42
                    define("RelativePath", ".");
                    define("PathToCurrentPage", "/");
                    define("FileName", "NewPage1.php");
                    include_once(RelativePath . "/Common.php");
                    include_once(RelativePath . "/Template.php");
                    include_once(RelativePath . "/Sorter.php");
                    include_once(RelativePath . "/Navigator.php");
                    //End Include Common Files

                    class clsRecordusers { //users Class @2-9BE1AF6F

                    //Variables @2-9E315808

                        // Public variables
                        public $ComponentType = "Record";
                        public $ComponentName;
                        public $Parent;
                        public $HTMLFormAction;
                        public $PressedButton;
                        public $Errors;
                        public $ErrorBlock;
                        public $FormSubmitted;
                        public $FormEnctype;
                        public $Visible;
                        public $IsEmpty;

                        public $CCSEvents = "";
                        public $CCSEventResult;

                        public $RelativePath = "";

                        public $InsertAllowed = false;
                        public $UpdateAllowed = false;
                        public $DeleteAllowed = false;
                        public $ReadAllowed   = false;
                        public $EditMode      = false;
                        public $ds;
                        public $DataSource;
                        public $ValidatingControls;
                        public $Controls;
                        public $Attributes;

                        // Class variables
                    //End Variables

                    //Class_Initialize Event @2-627C035C
                        function clsRecordusers($RelativePath, & $Parent)
                        {

                            global $FileName;
                            global $CCSLocales;
                            global $DefaultDateFormat;
                            $this->Visible = true;
                            $this->Parent = & $Parent;
                            $this->RelativePath = $RelativePath;
                            $this->Errors = new clsErrors();
                            $this->ErrorBlock = "Record users/Error";
                            $this->DataSource = new clsusersDataSource($this);
                            $this->ds = & $this->DataSource;
                            $this->InsertAllowed = true;
                            if($this->Visible)
                            {
                                $this->ComponentName = "users";
                                $this->Attributes = new clsAttributes($this->ComponentName . ":");
                                $CCSForm = explode(":", CCGetFromGet("ccsForm", ""), 2);
                                if(sizeof($CCSForm) == 1)
                                    $CCSForm[1] = "";
                                list($FormName, $FormMethod) = $CCSForm;
                                $this->EditMode = ($FormMethod == "Edit");
                                $this->FormEnctype = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                                $this->FormSubmitted = ($FormName == $this->ComponentName);
                                $Method = $this->FormSubmitted ? ccsPost : ccsGet;
                                $this->btn_register = new clsButton("btn_register", $Method, $this);
                                $this->username = new clsControl(ccsTextBox, "username", "Soldier", ccsText, "", CCGetRequestParam("username", $Method, NULL), $this);
                                $this->username->Required = true;
                                $this->user_email = new clsControl(ccsTextBox, "user_email", "User Email", ccsText, "", CCGetRequestParam("user_email", $Method, NULL), $this);
                                $this->user_email->Required = true;
                                $this->user_birthdate = new clsControl(ccsTextBox, "user_birthdate", "User Birthdate", ccsText, "", CCGetRequestParam("user_birthdate", $Method, NULL), $this);
                                $this->user_birthdate->Required = true;
                            }
                        }
                    //End Class_Initialize Event

                    //Initialize Method @2-052CBF13
                        function Initialize()
                        {

                            if(!$this->Visible)
                                return;

                            $this->DataSource->Parameters["urluid"] = CCGetFromGet("uid", NULL);
                        }
                    //End Initialize Method

                    //Validate Method @2-B7C6592D
                        function Validate()
                        {
                            global $CCSLocales;
                            $Validation = true;
                            $Where = "";
                            $Validation = ($this->username->Validate() && $Validation);
                            $Validation = ($this->user_email->Validate() && $Validation);
                            $Validation = ($this->user_birthdate->Validate() && $Validation);
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "OnValidate", $this);
                            $Validation =  $Validation && ($this->username->Errors->Count() == 0);
                            $Validation =  $Validation && ($this->user_email->Errors->Count() == 0);
                            $Validation =  $Validation && ($this->user_birthdate->Errors->Count() == 0);
                            return (($this->Errors->Count() == 0) && $Validation);
                        }
                    //End Validate Method

                    //CheckErrors Method @2-E8847328
                        function CheckErrors()
                        {
                            $errors = false;
                            $errors = ($errors || $this->username->Errors->Count());
                            $errors = ($errors || $this->user_email->Errors->Count());
                            $errors = ($errors || $this->user_birthdate->Errors->Count());
                            $errors = ($errors || $this->Errors->Count());
                            $errors = ($errors || $this->DataSource->Errors->Count());
                            return $errors;
                        }
                    //End CheckErrors Method

                    //Operation Method @2-6BA9892D
                        function Operation()
                        {
                            if(!$this->Visible)
                                return;

                            global $Redirect;
                            global $FileName;

                            $this->DataSource->Prepare();
                            if(!$this->FormSubmitted) {
                                $this->EditMode = $this->DataSource->AllParametersSet;
                                return;
                            }

                            if($this->FormSubmitted) {
                                $this->PressedButton = "btn_register";
                                if($this->btn_register->Pressed) {
                                    $this->PressedButton = "btn_register";
                                }
                            }
                            $Redirect = $FileName . "?" . CCGetQueryString("QueryString", array("ccsForm"));
                            if($this->Validate()) {
                                if($this->PressedButton == "btn_register") {
                                    if(!CCGetEvent($this->btn_register->CCSEvents, "OnClick", $this->btn_register) || !$this->InsertRow()) {
                                        $Redirect = "";
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                $Redirect = "";
                            }
                            if ($Redirect)
                                $this->DataSource->close();
                        }
                    //End Operation Method

                    //InsertRow Method @2-C62BC29D
                        function InsertRow()
                        {
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "BeforeInsert", $this);
                            if(!$this->InsertAllowed) return false;
                            $this->DataSource->username->SetValue($this->username->GetValue(true));
                            $this->DataSource->user_email->SetValue($this->user_email->GetValue(true));
                            $this->DataSource->user_birthdate->SetValue($this->user_birthdate->GetValue(true));
                            $this->DataSource->Insert();
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "AfterInsert", $this);
                            return (!$this->CheckErrors());
                        }
                    //End InsertRow Method

                    //Show Method @2-AE9867B3
                        function Show()
                        {
                            global $CCSUseAmp;
                            $Tpl = CCGetTemplate($this);
                            global $FileName;
                            global $CCSLocales;
                            $Error = "";

                            if(!$this->Visible)
                                return;

                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "BeforeSelect", $this);


                            $RecordBlock = "Record " . $this->ComponentName;
                            $ParentPath = $Tpl->block_path;
                            $Tpl->block_path = $ParentPath . "/" . $RecordBlock;
                            $this->EditMode = $this->EditMode && $this->ReadAllowed;
                            if($this->EditMode) {
                                if($this->DataSource->Errors->Count()){
                                    $this->Errors->AddErrors($this->DataSource->Errors);
                                    $this->DataSource->Errors->clear();
                                }
                                $this->DataSource->Open();
                                if($this->DataSource->Errors->Count() == 0 && $this->DataSource->next_record()) {
                                    $this->DataSource->SetValues();
                                    if(!$this->FormSubmitted){
                                        $this->username->SetValue($this->DataSource->username->GetValue());
                                        $this->user_email->SetValue($this->DataSource->user_email->GetValue());
                                        $this->user_birthdate->SetValue($this->DataSource->user_birthdate->GetValue());
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $this->EditMode = false;
                                }
                            }

                            if($this->FormSubmitted || $this->CheckErrors()) {
                                $Error = "";
                                $Error = ComposeStrings($Error, $this->username->Errors->ToString());
                                $Error = ComposeStrings($Error, $this->user_email->Errors->ToString());
                                $Error = ComposeStrings($Error, $this->user_birthdate->Errors->ToString());
                                $Error = ComposeStrings($Error, $this->Errors->ToString());
                                $Error = ComposeStrings($Error, $this->DataSource->Errors->ToString());
                                $Tpl->SetVar("Error", $Error);
                                $Tpl->Parse("Error", false);
                            }
                            $CCSForm = $this->EditMode ? $this->ComponentName . ":" . "Edit" : $this->ComponentName;
                            $this->HTMLFormAction = $FileName . "?" . CCAddParam(CCGetQueryString("QueryString", ""), "ccsForm", $CCSForm);
                            $Tpl->SetVar("Action", !$CCSUseAmp ? $this->HTMLFormAction : str_replace("&", "&amp;", $this->HTMLFormAction));
                            $Tpl->SetVar("HTMLFormName", $this->ComponentName);
                            $Tpl->SetVar("HTMLFormEnctype", $this->FormEnctype);
                            $this->btn_register->Visible = !$this->EditMode && $this->InsertAllowed;

                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "BeforeShow", $this);
                            $this->Attributes->Show();
                            if(!$this->Visible) {
                                $Tpl->block_path = $ParentPath;
                                return;
                            }

                            $this->btn_register->Show();
                            $this->username->Show();
                            $this->user_email->Show();
                            $this->user_birthdate->Show();
                            $Tpl->parse();
                            $Tpl->block_path = $ParentPath;
                            $this->DataSource->close();
                        }
                    //End Show Method

                    } //End users Class @2-FCB6E20C

                    class clsusersDataSource extends clsDBlocalhost {  //usersDataSource Class @2-5EDEDCFF

                    //DataSource Variables @2-8A9D7D42
                        public $Parent = "";
                        public $CCSEvents = "";
                        public $CCSEventResult;
                        public $ErrorBlock;
                        public $CmdExecution;

                        public $InsertParameters;
                        public $wp;
                        public $AllParametersSet;

                        public $InsertFields = array();

                        // Datasource fields
                        public $username;
                        public $user_email;
                        public $user_birthdate;
                    //End DataSource Variables

                    //DataSourceClass_Initialize Event @2-56B8B1F7
                        function clsusersDataSource(& $Parent)
                        {
                            $this->Parent = & $Parent;
                            $this->ErrorBlock = "Record users/Error";
                            $this->Initialize();
                            $this->username = new clsField("username", ccsText, "");

                            $this->user_email = new clsField("user_email", ccsText, "");

                            $this->user_birthdate = new clsField("user_birthdate", ccsText, "");


                            $this->InsertFields["soldier"] = array("Name" => "soldier", "Value" => "", "DataType" => ccsText, "OmitIfEmpty" => 1);
                            $this->InsertFields["user_email"] = array("Name" => "user_email", "Value" => "", "DataType" => ccsText, "OmitIfEmpty" => 1);
                            $this->InsertFields["user_birthdate"] = array("Name" => "user_birthdate", "Value" => "", "DataType" => ccsText, "OmitIfEmpty" => 1);
                        }
                    //End DataSourceClass_Initialize Event

                    //Prepare Method @2-DC2F5FB8
                        function Prepare()
                        {
                            global $CCSLocales;
                            global $DefaultDateFormat;
                            $this->wp = new clsSQLParameters($this->ErrorBlock);
                            $this->wp->AddParameter("1", "urluid", ccsInteger, "", "", $this->Parameters["urluid"], "", false);
                            $this->AllParametersSet = $this->wp->AllParamsSet();
                            $this->wp->Criterion[1] = $this->wp->Operation(opEqual, "uid", $this->wp->GetDBValue("1"), $this->ToSQL($this->wp->GetDBValue("1"), ccsInteger),false);
                            $this->Where = 
                                 $this->wp->Criterion[1];
                        }
                    //End Prepare Method

                    //Open Method @2-B071412E
                        function Open()
                        {
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "BeforeBuildSelect", $this->Parent);
                            $this->SQL = "SELECT * \n\n" .
                            "FROM users {SQL_Where} {SQL_OrderBy}";
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "BeforeExecuteSelect", $this->Parent);
                            $this->query(CCBuildSQL($this->SQL, $this->Where, $this->Order));
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "AfterExecuteSelect", $this->Parent);
                        }
                    //End Open Method

                    //SetValues Method @2-1C83BB75
                        function SetValues()
                        {
                            $this->username->SetDBValue($this->f("soldier"));
                            $this->user_email->SetDBValue($this->f("user_email"));
                            $this->user_birthdate->SetDBValue($this->f("user_birthdate"));
                        }
                    //End SetValues Method

                    //Insert Method @2-D2F97CD9
                        function Insert()
                        {
                            global $CCSLocales;
                            global $DefaultDateFormat;
                            $this->CmdExecution = true;
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "BeforeBuildInsert", $this->Parent);
                            $this->InsertFields["soldier"]["Value"] = $this->username->GetDBValue(true);
                            $this->InsertFields["user_email"]["Value"] = $this->user_email->GetDBValue(true);
                            $this->InsertFields["user_birthdate"]["Value"] = $this->user_birthdate->GetDBValue(true);
                            $this->SQL = CCBuildInsert("users", $this->InsertFields, $this);
                            $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "BeforeExecuteInsert", $this->Parent);
                            if($this->Errors->Count() == 0 && $this->CmdExecution) {
                                $this->query($this->SQL);
                                $this->CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($this->CCSEvents, "AfterExecuteInsert", $this->Parent);
                            }
                        }
                    //End Insert Method

                    } //End usersDataSource Class @2-FCB6E20C

                    //Initialize Page @1-2A4101A9
                    // Variables
                    $FileName = "";
                    $Redirect = "";
                    $Tpl = "";
                    $TemplateFileName = "";
                    $BlockToParse = "";
                    $ComponentName = "";
                    $Attributes = "";

                    // Events;
                    $CCSEvents = "";
                    $CCSEventResult = "";
                    $TemplateSource = "";

                    $FileName = FileName;
                    $Redirect = "";
                    $TemplateFileName = "NewPage1.html";
                    $BlockToParse = "main";
                    $TemplateEncoding = "UTF-8";
                    $ContentType = "text/html";
                    $PathToRoot = "./";
                    $PathToRootOpt = "";
                    $Scripts = "|";
                    $Charset = $Charset ? $Charset : "utf-8";
                    //End Initialize Page

                    //Before Initialize @1-E870CEBC
                    $CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($CCSEvents, "BeforeInitialize", $MainPage);
                    //End Before Initialize

                    //Initialize Objects @1-1F103AC9
                    $DBlocalhost = new clsDBlocalhost();
                    $MainPage->Connections["localhost"] = & $DBlocalhost;
                    $Attributes = new clsAttributes("page:");
                    $Attributes->SetValue("pathToRoot", $PathToRoot);
                    $MainPage->Attributes = & $Attributes;

                    // Controls
                    $users = new clsRecordusers("", $MainPage);
                    $MainPage->users = & $users;
                    $users->Initialize();
                    $ScriptIncludes = "";
                    $SList = explode("|", $Scripts);
                    foreach ($SList as $Script) {
                        if ($Script != "") $ScriptIncludes = $ScriptIncludes . "<script src=\"" . $PathToRoot . $Script . "\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\n";
                    }
                    $Attributes->SetValue("scriptIncludes", $ScriptIncludes);

                    $CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($CCSEvents, "AfterInitialize", $MainPage);

                    if ($Charset) {
                        header("Content-Type: " . $ContentType . "; charset=" . $Charset);
                    } else {
                        header("Content-Type: " . $ContentType);
                    }
                    //End Initialize Objects

                    //Initialize HTML Template @1-28F2FDD6
                    $CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($CCSEvents, "OnInitializeView", $MainPage);
                    $Tpl = new clsTemplate($FileEncoding, $TemplateEncoding);
                    if (strlen($TemplateSource)) {
                        $Tpl->LoadTemplateFromStr($TemplateSource, $BlockToParse, "UTF-8");
                    } else {
                        $Tpl->LoadTemplate(PathToCurrentPage . $TemplateFileName, $BlockToParse, "UTF-8");
                    }
                    $Tpl->SetVar("CCS_PathToRoot", $PathToRoot);
                    $Tpl->block_path = "/$BlockToParse";
                    $CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($CCSEvents, "BeforeShow", $MainPage);
                    $Attributes->SetValue("pathToRoot", "");
                    $Attributes->Show();
                    //End Initialize HTML Template

                    //Execute Components @1-0C9864E9
                    $users->Operation();
                    //End Execute Components

                    //Go to destination page @1-810C207B
                    if($Redirect)
                    {
                        $CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($CCSEvents, "BeforeUnload", $MainPage);
                        $DBlocalhost->close();
                        header("Location: " . $Redirect);
                        unset($users);
                        unset($Tpl);
                        exit;
                    }
                    //End Go to destination page

                    //Show Page @1-E3A8594F
                    $users->Show();
                    $Tpl->block_path = "";
                    $Tpl->Parse($BlockToParse, false);
                    if (!isset($main_block)) $main_block = $Tpl->GetVar($BlockToParse);
                    $main_block = CCConvertEncoding($main_block, $FileEncoding,             $TemplateEncoding);
                    $CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent($CCSEvents, "BeforeOutput", $MainPage);
                    if ($CCSEventResult) echo $main_block;
                    //End Show Page

                    //Unload Page @1-4215F8E1
                    $CCSEventResult = CCGetEvent  ($CCSEvents, "BeforeUnload", $MainPage);
                    $DBlocalhost->close();
                    unset($users);
                    unset($Tpl);
                    //End Unload Page


                    ?>
```

Comment: I am using a IDE to create this

Comment: Please post your existing code!

Comment: Rewriting? You are getting ahead of yourself. Just put `method="post"` on your `<form>` tag.

Comment: I am using a IDE called code charge I figured out what I am looking for is a no refresh register page with redirect if there are no errors like invalid content or unique email

Comment: I appreciate the responses but haven't gotten anywhere thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit the information via POST. The way you are submitting the data across is from a GET HTTP request. The best thing to do is submit it over via post data. I am assuming your frontend call is using ajax for the form submission? if not and using a simple form change method to POST. If it is using ajax, I would need to know if you are using something like jquery or crafting the XHR request yourself, but if you are doing it that way I would assume you would know the difference.

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: I am looking to make it a no refresh but if no errors it will redirect like email in use or invalid

Comment: Use an Ajax request for it. Using a xmlhttp request. Or use a Ajax library to set up the request and have it called when form is submitted.

Comment: OK the form is set to post the issue is validation if I use default validation if it won't post error messages with out the ?action-signup I would like to use ajax to validate if unique or required

Comment: You would add validation in JavaScript to check the values before it is posted. Or better practice would be check the values in JavaScript and on the server side. You would get the values and of the values didn't match your validation on the server you would return a failure and give them an error message saying that the information provided was not valid. The Ajax request itself doesn't do validation

Comment: Geo I appreciate all your help I'm not good at all with java is there a script you could point me to?